# Heroku Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app

Tags: php, heroku

Deployment to Heroku for my project has been working fine until today. Last update to my composer file was including a php class to my class map in composer.json. Now Heroku Deployment fails with this error message

```
-----> Removing .DS_Store files
-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
-----> PHP app detected
-----> No runtime required in composer.json, defaulting to PHP 5.6.11.
-----> Installing system packages...
     - PHP 5.6.11
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
!     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app
```

I have tried updating composer, but updating composer.lock doesn't solve this issue for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is having problems at the moment: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/792

Don't worry, it's not just you!

Comment: Thanks @Porbean!! I lost hours trying out different answers here at stackoverflow.